# How to access to AdvancedDataGrid combobox value

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, advanceddatagrid

I try to access AdvancedDataGrid - AdvancedDataGridColumn  value? Its ComboBox and I use this code to access:

```
'"+ myGrid_olculer.dataProvider[k].data + "'
```

Then the result is:

```
INSERT INTO [INN_T_OPTSIPARIS]  ( GAIN) values (' [object Object]'  )
```

For combobox, I use this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="GAIN"    dataField="GAIN"    editable="true"   rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="data">
<mx:itemRenderer>
<mx:Component>
<mx:ComboBox creationComplete="GAIN_init()">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private var _data:Object;
[Bindable]
override public function set data(o:Object):void {
_data = o;
if(Number(o.GAIN) <= 0) {
  this.selectedIndex = 0;}
else {this.selectedIndex = Number(o.GAIN);}
}
override public function get data():Object {return _data;}
private function GAIN_init():void {
                                            this.dataProvider = ["Evet", "Hayır"];
                                            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, update);}
private function update(event:MouseEvent):void {if(this.selectedIndex == 0) _data.GAIN = "-1";                                                 else _data.GAIN = this.selectedIndex.toString();}
]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:ComboBox>
</mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

put chnage event on combobox and set new selected value as

data.GAIN=combox.selectedLabel

now latest value you can access

data.GAIN or dataprovider Oject.root tag[rowindex].GAIN

Comment: i try it, but some values is missing, or value is [object object]